# Ghost with Docker for theme development, CMS fails loading files

Tags: docker, ghost-blog

I want to set up my **GhostCMS theme development environment** with Ghost's official Docker image. For that, I am making a container with the following command:

```
docker run -d --rm -e NODE_ENV=development -p 3001:2368 -v $PWD:/var/lib/ghost/current/content/themes/customtheme ghost
```

Notice that:

- I am using the volume (-v) flag to pass my theme's path.
- I get into the container and make a symbolic link from the directory `/var/lib/ghost/current/content/themes/customtheme` into `/var/lib/ghost/content/themes/customtheme`.

The theme will appear in the theme selection menu of GhostCMS's admin dessign settings. Yet, when I try to select it, it fails with:

[image: error message from ghost]

What am I doing wrong? What is the correct way to use GhostCMS's image for development if any?

Comment: I know nothing about Ghost but I know symbolic links in container can lead to different behaviour. Have you tried copy-pasting the themes inside the container to the right position, overwriting the symbolic links. If it works like that you at least know the culprit.

Comment: @JustLudo Yeah, I tried that. Same issue

Comment: That is too bad. Are there no logs or error statements visible inside the docker logs? I would assume the container outputs something regarding what could be wrong? Do you have this issue with other themes as well? If possible, can you run Ghost locally and see if that theme causes errors then as well?

Comment: @JustLudo That's one of the biggest issues I had. The container runs, but it seems that I am doing something wrong for the Ghost setup or theme files

Comment: Prob. best way to tackle this is to peel down the issue. Get it running locally if possible. If it fails for other themes make sure keep trying until the configuration matches the desired config. Etc. etc. Unless someone over here explicitly uses Ghost inside a container as well, I doubt you'll get timely response.